# How to clear a window in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, widget, pysimplegui

I am using PySimpleGUI to build a GUI. How do you clear all the widgets on the window? In tkinter you have the code:

```
widget.destroy()
```

If you attempt this in PySimpleGUI you get the error:

```
NameError: name 'RWG' is not defined
```

if my widget is called `RWG`. I tried making `RWG` a `global` variable but I got the same error. Can I have some help?
My code that gets the error:

```
def oof():
    RWG.destroy()


import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.theme("DarkAmber")
layout = [[sg.Text("Don't Even Try!!!")],
          [sg.Button("RWG")]]

window = sg.Window("Don't Even Try It", layout).Finalize()
window.Maximize()

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == "RWG":
        oof()
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can reproduce the error and inspect.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I assume it was done before you edited the question.

Comment: There can be various reasons, you might want to kindly ask for a feedback on your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clear elements with:

```
window.FindElement(key).Update('')
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: ** Warning - FindElement should not be used to look up elements. window[key] or window.find_element are recommended. **